# reverseLayout arrangement order of LazyVerticalGrid in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

After LazyVerticalGrid sets reverseLayout to true：

The blue background is the actual index order.

The red font is the order I expect, how can I achieve this order?

```kotlin
    LazyVerticalGrid(columns = GridCells.Fixed(3),
        reverseLayout = true,
        contentPadding = paddingValues,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom) {

        // ...
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use CompositionLocalProvider to provide right to left direction. This is can also be used for Side navigation that opens from right side either.

```
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalLayoutDirection provides LayoutDirection.Rtl) 
{
      LazyVerticalGrid(columns = GridCells.Fixed(3),
        reverseLayout = true,
        contentPadding = paddingValues,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom) {

        // ...
    }
}
```

[image]